# hdf5r libhdf5_hl.so.200: cannot open shared object file

Tags: r, linux, hdf5

I am installing hdf5r on a RedHat EC2 in the cloud,
and I am getting the following error when calling the library (below). How can I solve it ?

```
> library("hdf5r")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘hdf5r’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/lalala/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/hdf5r/libs/hdf5r.so':
  libhdf5_hl.so.200: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/libopenblasp-r0.3.3.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Did you get any error message when running `install.packages('hdf5r')`?

Comment: How did you install `libhdf5_hl.so`, and is that path in your LD_CONFIG?  R doesn't support loading libraries dynamically if they're no in the search path to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Can [this GitHub post](https://github.com/hhoeflin/hdf5r/issues/106#issuecomment-1006128228) help?

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I could solve the problem relatively easily shall I have a simple PC to work with. The issue is that I do work on an EC2 that is connected to local network drives, R is installed on EC2, the /home folder is on the local drives, and I do not know where to find .Renviron.